# Drupal commerce: Purpose of utilizing different product types?

Tags: nodes, commerce

I'm trying to figure out product types in Drupal commerce. Why would you want to use more than one product type?

Couldn't you just use one product type?

I could see that different product types have different fields. Is that the primary reason?

Or is it because there an ease of use for utilizing product types in views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different set of fields should be the main reason for different product types. In my opinion, it is the same reason which puts us in the position of creating new content types.

Different set of fields might seem trivial, but if you are using rules/triggers to do different things to a unique set of fields, then that's altogether a different feature.

Hope this explains the difference.